# How to select a subset of columns from table with list in kdb+/q?

Tags: kdb

Given the following table:

```
time     | col1  col2  col3  ...
--------------------------------
10:53:02 | 89    89    76    ...
...
```

How does one select a subset of columns from this table (including the index) referenced by a list of column names i.e. `cols:('col1';'col3');`
Whereby the expected result would be:

```
time     | col1  col3
----------------------
10:53:02 | 89    89   
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to point out, ```cols``` is not a valid variable name in KDB+, as it is already the name of a built-in function. Usually a lower case ```c``` will suffice. In the above,  ```cols:('col1';'col3')``` would be better written as ```c:`col1`col2```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a take (#) keyword with the each right (/:) adverb. 
So q will take the subset of sym and price columns from the table t and return a table with your key and your required subset of data

```
q)t:([time:.z.z+ 1 2];sym:`a`b;price:10 20;vol:30 40)
q)c:`sym`price
q)c#/:t
time                   | sym price
-----------------------| ---------
2019.09.05T07:56:36.069| a   10
2019.09.06T07:56:36.069| b   20
```

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to do this:

```
q) t:([time:.z.z+ 1 2];sym:`a`b;price:10 20;vol:30 40)
```

Columns required in output:

```
q) c:`sym`price
```

Add table key columns to above list:

```
q) c:keys[t],c
```

**Using Functional Select:**

```
q) keys[t] xkey ?[`t;();0b;c!c]
```

**Using Take(#) operator**

```
q) keys[t] xkey c#0!t
```

Output:

```
time                   | sym price
-----------------------| ---------
2019.09.04T23:05:21.577| a   10
2019.09.05T23:05:21.577| b   20
```